# How to switch active window to form view or code view using envDTE?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, add-in

I am creating a visual studio add-in, i need to switch active document to code view or form view using code. 
please any one can help?

Comment: What's the context?  What document type are you working with?

Comment: actually i want to switch Between Windows Form Design View to Code View or viceversa by using code. but i got the answer myself. I am posting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

thank God i got the answer my self :)

here is the link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/324611/Extending-Visual-Studio-Part-2-Creating-Addins